# JFileChooser calls file explorer twice before item is selected

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm trying to use JFileChooser to get the directory of a database file for my inventory control software.

The problem is that JFileChooser only gets the directory of the file after the file explorer is displayed twice and the file is chosen twice.

The code is below:

```
package groupassignment;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author ashraf141298
 */ 
public class GetDatabase {
    static Connection con;
    static Statement st;
    static ResultSet rs;

    public GetDatabase() {
        connect();
    }

    public String getFileDirectory() {
        JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
        File db = null;
        String directory;

        if(filechooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            db = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Opening file: " + db);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file was chosen or an error occured");
            System.exit(0);
        };

        directory = db.toString();
        return directory;
    }

    public void connect() {
        try{
            String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + getFileDirectory();

            // Attempt to connect to the database
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);

            // Extract data from the table using SQL sta
            st = con.createStatement();
            String query = "select * from ProductBarcodes";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        } catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to connect to database", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetDatabase database = new GetDatabase();
        DisplayDatabase gui = new DisplayDatabase();
    }
}
```

Code for DisplayDatabase:

```
package groupassignment;
import static groupassignment.GetDatabase.rs;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author ashraf141298
 */
public class DisplayDatabase extends GetDatabase {
    public DisplayDatabase() {
        display();
    }

    public void display() {
        // It creates and displays the table
        JTable table = null;

        try {
            table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to create JTable");
        }

        // Closes the Connection
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table), "Current Stocklist", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        // get the names of columns 
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        // get the data of the table
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }

        // return the database in TableModel form
        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

     }                

}
```

Comment: @FastSnail same here, once I commented out the `DisplayDatabase gui = new DisplayDatabase();` so it would compile. I suspect that the 2nd file chooser is appearing due to the commented code line. OP: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: So running the code (without actually connecting to a database) seems to work just fine for me

Comment: I added the code for the other class (i.e. DisplayDatabase). The class converts the obtained result set to tablemodel and displays it as a JTable using JOptionPane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have extends `DisplayDatabase` with `GetDatabase` class

```
DisplayDatabase extends GetDatabase{
  ...
}
```

so when you create a new instance of `GetDatabase` class constructor of super class [`GetDatabase`] get invoked and connect method get called again.

so you get another `jfilechooser` popup window.

```
 GetDatabase database = new GetDatabase();
```

so how to fix

if you don't want to inherit anything from `GetDatabase` class you can remove extends part.

but if you want to inherit from `GetDatabase` class then,

instead of connect db from constructor , you can do it from a method.

```
public GetDatabase() {
   // connect();// not here
}

public void ConnectDatabase(){
    connect();
}
```

so you call this method .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GetDatabase database = new GetDatabase();
    database.ConnectDatabase();
    DisplayDatabase gui = new DisplayDatabase();
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

May be the function is being triggered more than once, your code for calling file chooser seems to work fine.